# Get value of TD cell in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr data-uid="2639f8d8-5459-42fb-b51c-b071db6c1541" role="row">
  <td class="" role="gridcell">1</td>
  <td class="" role="gridcell">06/12/2018</td>
  <td class="" role="gridcell">Feeding</td> 
  <td class="" role="gridcell">some long text data</td>

  <td class="k-command-cell" role="gridcell">
  <a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-ViewDetails" 
  href="#">View Details</a></td>

</tr>
```

There are many rows in the table like this one.... I need to get the ID value which in this case is '1'. I have tried to get the attribute role value but no luck.

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? There are [**lots of hits** for "\[js\] get value of td"](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+get+value+of+td). (More on searching [here](/help/searching).) Is it selecting it that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Please post relevant Script code of whatever you tried.

Comment: research `.text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly your question is, but I'm posting an simple example of collecting all ids in the table.

```js
$(function(){
  var ids = $('tr').map(function(){ 
        return $(this).children('td').first().text()
  }).get();
  console.log(ids); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr data-uid="2639f8d8-5459-42fb-b51c-b071db6c1541" role="row">
  <td class="" role="gridcell">1</td>
  <td class="" role="gridcell">06/12/2018</td>
  <td class="" role="gridcell">Feeding</td> 
  <td class="" role="gridcell">some long text data</td>

  <td class="k-command-cell" role="gridcell">
  <a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-ViewDetails" 
  href="#">View Details</a></td>

</tr>
<tr data-uid="2639f8d8-5459-42fb-b51c-b071db6c1541" role="row">
  <td class="" role="gridcell">2</td>
  <td class="" role="gridcell">07/12/2018</td>
  <td class="" role="gridcell">Feeding 2</td> 
  <td class="" role="gridcell">some long text data ...</td>

  <td class="k-command-cell" role="gridcell">
  <a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-ViewDetails" 
  href="#">View Details</a></td>

</tr>
</table>
```